# Array Expansion

Tags: bash, array

I am having unexpected results in expanding an array.  I am hoping someone can shed some light on why I am seeing what I am seeing.  I am trying to populate an array using fdisk -l to fill it and only getting a single element.  The code:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a PARTITIONS=();

PARTITIONS=$(fdisk -l ubuntu-minimal-16.04-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi-2.img | grep -i ubuntu-minimal-16.04-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi-2.img | sed '/Disk/d' | cut -d " " -f1)

echo "PARTITIONS[@]:${PARTITIONS[@]}"

echo "ELEMENT 0: ${PARTITIONS[0]}"

echo "ELEMENT 1: ${PARTITIONS[1]}"
```

Output:

```
 PARTITIONS[@]:ubuntu-minimal-16.04-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi-2.img1 ubuntu-minimal-16.04-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi-2.img2

 ELEMENT 0: ubuntu-minimal-16.04-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi-2.img1 ubuntu-minimal-16.04-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi-2.img2

 ELEMENT 1:
```

There is no element 1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting to be in element 1? If you're expecting it to be ``ubuntu-minimal-16.04-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi-2.img2``, you may notice that it is part of element 0.

Answer (score 6):

When assigning to an array:

```
array=( elements )
```

I.e.,

```
PARTITIONS=( $(fdisk ... ) )
```

Answer (score 5):

When a string is assigned to an array, it is assigned to its first element.  Observe:

```
$ declare -a x
$ x=$(date)
$ declare -p x
declare -a x='([0]="Fri Jul 15 11:09:59 PDT 2016")'
```

Here `$(date)` is the string that results from command substitution.  (This is like your fdisk pipeline but simpler.)  `declare -p` is used here to show the exact contents of a bash variable.

If you want word splitting on the string, use parens like so:

```
$ x=($(date))
$ declare -p x
declare -a x='([0]="Fri" [1]="Jul" [2]="15" [3]="11:10:08" [4]="PDT" [5]="2016")'
```